# linq order by Month Name and Year (MMM yyyy string)

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

How can i order by the month name and year in linq, it currently orders alphabetically and that is causing an issue when the report is displayed

I am looking for Nov 2011, Dec 2011, Jan 2012, Feb 2012

my main concern is with result MonthList as it is the union between monthlist1 and monthlist2

Thanks for the help and insight

```
var monthlist1 = data.
    Select(x => new { wkdate = x.WKENDDATE }).
    OrderBy(y => y.wkdate).
    Select(m => new { 
        monthname = m.wkdate.ToString("MMM yyyy", 
                                      CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US")) 
        }).
    Distinct().
    ToList();

var monthlist2 =
    data.Select(x => new { wkdate = 
          ExportHelper.getSplitEndDate(x.WKENDDATE).AddDays(1)})
         .OrderBy(y => y.wkdate)
         .Where(l => ExportHelper.isSplitWeek(l.wkdate.AddDays(-6), l.wkdate) == true)
         .Select(m => new { 
                   monthname = m.wkdate.ToString("MMM yyyy", 
                   CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US")) 
               })
              .Distinct()
              .ToList();

var monthlist = 
    monthlist1.
    Union(monthlist2).
    Distinct().
    OrderBy(m=> m.monthname).
    ToList();
```

Comment: Please format the code in your question so that it is more readable. Ideally there will be no horizontal scroll bar.

Comment: Order by month name can become sort of a problem if the application is multilingual

Comment: What is the problem you are having with the current code?

Comment: its ordering alphabetically by month name

Comment: So, you want `Apr, Aug, Dec ...` etc.?

Comment: i actually want Nov 2011 Dec 2011 Jan 2012 Feb 2012

Comment: The problem is that his code **is** sorting alphabetically. OP wants the dates sorted in **calendar order** instead.

Comment: You are supposed to do the orderby after the distinct, as officially distinct returns unordered.

Comment: Dont format the dates until you've sorted them after the union

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's sorting alphabetically because `wkdate` is a `String` value and not a `DateTime`. You need to parse it first:

```
var monthlist = monthlist1.Union(monthlist2)
    .Distinct()
    // monthname is a String in format MMM yyyy
    .OrderBy(m => DateTime.Parse(m.monthname))
    .ToList();
```

I'm assuming that since your current `wkdate` values follow a format of `MMM yyyy` (e.g. `Apr 2012`) they will **all** parse properly. This is a bold assumption, I know.

You will also have to format the values back into a `String` representation for your final result.

Comment: the issue is on monthlist where i am doing the union as that is my main result set, would this help

Comment: @bugz You're right - only the final `Union()` needs to change. Try the updated sample.

Comment: Thanks Yuck i got my solution for order by month from your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
var monthlist1 = data.
    Select(x => new { wkdate = x.WKENDDATE }).
    OrderBy(x=> CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(x.Month)).
    ThenBy(x=> x.Year).
    Select(m => new { 
        monthname = m.wkdate.ToString("MMM yyyy", 
                                      CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US")) 
        }).
    Distinct().
    ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Somthing like

```
var monthlist1 = data.Select(m => new DateTime(m.WKENDDATE.Year,
                                                 m.WKENDDATE.Month,
                                                 1);

var monthlist2a = 
    data.Select(x => 
        new { wkdate = ExportHelper.getSplitEndDate(x.WKENDDATE).AddDay(1)})
    .Where(l => 
        ExportHelper.isSplitWeek(l.wkdate.AddDays(-6), l.wkdate) == true);

var monthlist2b = monthlist2a.Select(m => new DateTime(m.WKENDDATE.Year,
                                                 m.WKENDDATE.Month,
                                                 1);


var monthlist = monthlist1.Union(monthlist2b).Distinct()
                 .OrderBy(m => (m.Year * 100) + m.Month)
                 .Select(m => 
        m.ToString("MMM yyyy", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"));
```

This way you avoid the unnecessary formatting and parsing